# Android scale button margin with background image of parent view

Tags: android, image, layout, resources, dimension

In my app, I have a couple rows of buttons that share a single background image when not pressed, but get an individual background image when pressed.

To clarify myself: the buttons share a parent with a big background image, so the shadows don't interfere. When I press on a button, the transparent background image of the pressed button changes to a version that's pressed down and is put over the background image of the parent. There is a margin on the buttons because the mutual background image has shadows that I don't want the buttons to be on top off.

The current code works great on most devices, but on a tablet the margins are off so the buttons are bigger than the other buttons when pressed.

I know there are different units of measure (dp, sp, pt, px, mm and im), but I can't seem to get one to work like I want it to.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_volume"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:background="@drawable/knoppen">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Btn_VolDown"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:background="@drawable/mainbtn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/voldown"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_volDown" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Btn_Mute"
            android:onClick="onUdpBtnClicked"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:background="@drawable/mainbtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/mute"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_mute" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Btn_VolUp"
            android:onClick="onUdpBtnClicked"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:background="@drawable/mainbtn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/volup"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_volUp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

So to summarize: I have an image with a certain margin where I don't want anything on top off and I have a button where I have to specify that margin, but I need it to scale with the image

I hope I'm clear enough and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not sure if its what u want but if what u mean with an image is ImageView then u can use a linear layout to make your other stuff boxed to stay below your ImageView so it wont ever get on top off that.

Or maybe you can use something like this too

```
LayoutParams params1 = (LayoutParams)twoLetter.getLayoutParams();//twoletter-imageview
                params1.height = 70;
                params1.setMargins(0, 210, 0, 0);//top margin -210 here
                twoLetter.setLayoutParams(params1);//setting layout params
                twoLetter.setImageResource(R.drawable.oo);
```

i'm not sure what you are trying so sorry for not being so helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding for a while, I expected stackoverflow to send me an email when someone responded.
What I'm trying to achieve is this:
http://i.imgur.com/oa2Sjjl.png

But on a Nexus 10 (2K resolution), I get his:
http://imgur.com/wiK1zSI

I'm trying to figure out which margins I should use to get it to look good on all devices